# What is the right import for lodash constructor?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am working on some Angular projects and use lodash as helper. I read a lot of articles about how to import lodash the right way to make the bundle size smaller. But I got a problem with my current implementation because I use lodash chaining method.

```
return _(items)
  .groupBy(x => x.vote.code)
  .map(items => items)
  .value();
```

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

I read import * is not good. 
My problem is how can I import `_(items)` so that my import looks like below?

```
import groupBy from 'lodash/groupBy';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reduce your bundle size, you want to avoid importing the whole of Lodash. Instead, you can just import the functions you want - `groupBy` and `map`.

However, in this case you are also using chaining, which *does* require all of Lodash. You can re-write your code using [`flow`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flow) and use the [functional programming-friendly bundle of Lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) to replace  the chaining:

```
import {flow, groupBy, map} from 'lodash/fp';

/* ... */

const chainReplacement = flow(groupBy(x => x.vote.code), map(items => items));
return chainReplacement(items)
```

Here is a quick illustration that the two produce equivalent results:

```js
const {flow, groupBy, map} = _;

//sample data
const items = [
  { vote: { code: "1" }, name: "Alice"},
  { vote: { code: "2" }, name: "Bob"},
  { vote: { code: "1" }, name: "Carol"},
  { vote: { code: "2" }, name: "Dave"},
  { vote: { code: "1" }, name: "Edel"}
];

//using literally the same functions
const groupByCallback = x => x.vote.code;
const mapCallback = items => items.length;

const chain = _(items)
  .groupBy(groupByCallback)
  .map(mapCallback);

const chainReplacement = flow(
  groupBy(groupByCallback), 
  map(mapCallback)
);

console.log("chain", chain.value())
console.log("chainReplacement", chainReplacement(items))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-fp/0.10.4/lodash-fp.min.js"></script>
```

I made some data that matched your usage of `groupBy` but then had to modify the `map` callback because it didn't make sense. I assume because it was for illustrative purposes. So I swapped it for `items => items.length` to get the count of each group. It's not very meaningful but it's also for illustrative purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to import one function or group of functions:

```
import { groupBy } from "lodash";
```

Comment: What is the equivalent method for `_(items)`? Because of this, I need to import *

Comment: Well, you'd need to actually `import *` because the `_` is the function.